# How to convert a repetitive block of code to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've got a sequence of code that will be run for the large majority of input items in a contact form; for the sake of lines of code, I want to have this operate as a function. Here is an example of the block:

```
$('#country_code').blur(function() {
var countryCode = $('#country_code').val();
    if(validateNumber(countryCode) == true) {
        if(countryCode.lastIndexOf('+') != 0) {
            countryCode = countryCode.replace('+', '');
            $('#country_code').val('+' + countryCode);
        }
    }
    else {
        countryCode = '';
        $('#country_code').val(countryCode);
    }
});
```

And I want to create a function like the following:

```
function validateElements(elementName, variableName, validationFunction, indexValue, indexPosition) {
    $(elementName).blur(function() {
        var variableName = $(elementName).val();
        if(validationFunction(variableName) == true) {
            if(variableName.lastIndexOf(indexValue) != indexPosition) {
                variableName = variableName.replace(indexValue, '');
                $(elementName).val(indexValue + variableName);
            }
        }
        else {
            variableName = '';
            $(elementname).val(variableName);
        }
    });
}
```

In which I'd call the function like follows:

```
validateElements('#country_code', 'countryCode', 'validateNumber', '+', 0);
```

Comment: The questions the title, I was confused too

Comment: Question is: how can I make this work? As right now, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it so that you call your function as follows:

```
validateElements($('#country_code'), 'countryCode', 'validateNumber', '+', 0);
```

And the change your function:

```
function validateElements(obj, variableName, validationFunction, indexValue, indexPosition) {
    obj.blur(function() {
        var variableName = obj.val();
        if(validationFunction(variableName) == true) {
            if(variableName.lastIndexOf(indexValue) != indexPosition) {
                variableName = variableName.replace(indexValue, '');
                obj.val(indexValue + variableName);
            }
        }
        else {
            variableName = '';
            obj.val(variableName);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: gave it a try, still no luck.

Comment: The best thing to do is to comment out lines of code one line at a time, run the code, and see when it does work.  When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean the blur event is being called and something inside the event is incorrect or is the blur event never even being called?